# Multiple instances of rule with FTP.remote as input

Tags: snakemake

I'm working on snakemake workflow that uses files located on an FTP server as input for the first rule via an FTP.remote() call.  The workflow executes just fine, but the FTP downloads always execute serially - even when the DAG and the command line options would allow multipe instances of the rule to run in parallel. I presume this is because I've only opened one FTP connection outside the rule, so that connection is shared by all calls to FTP.remote.  Is it possible to get snakemake to open an FTP connection for each instance of the rule so that I can be downloading multiple files from the FTP server in parallel?  A snippet from the rule is below:

```
from snakemake.remote.FTP import RemoteProvider as FTPRemoteProvider
FTP = FTPRemoteProvider()

rule cram2bam:
    input:
        cram = lambda wildcards: FTP.remote(expand("ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/{cram}", cram = config['Samples'][wildcards.sample]['WES'])),
```

Comment: Did you try putting the `FTPRemoteProvider()` instead of `FTP` in the input function?